# Using stash embed var as a conditional in channel:entries parameters

Tags: stash

I'm revisiting a very old EE site, I had an embed that was used heavily in the site. The embed has some embed variables that could be used in simple conditionals to turn on and off various weblog parameters:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
  channel="{embed:my_channel_id}" 
  orderby="{embed:my_orderby}" 
  {if embed:my_member_id}author_id="{embed:my_member_id}"{/if} 
  {if embed:my_paginate}paginate="{embed:my_paginate}" {/if} 
  ...
}
```

I want to convert this to a stash embed, but I'm stuck on how to include the stash vars in simple conditionals.  I want to do something like the following:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="st_images" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2" parse_conditionals="yes"}
  {exp:channel:entries 
    channel="{stash:_channel}"  
    orderby="{stash:_orderby}" 
    {if {stash:_author_id} != ""}author_id="{stash:_author_id}"{/if}
    {if {stash:_paginate} != ""}paginate="bottom"{/if}
    {if {stash:_paginate} != ""}disable="member_data|categories|pagination"{/if}
    {if {stash:_paginate} == ""}disable="member_data|categories"{/if}
    ...
  }
```

Any ideas how I can use stash to turn on or off parameters in this way?

Thanks

Comment: How/where are you setting the stash vars? Ex: `{stash:_channel}`

Comment: the code above is in the stash embed file.  Those stash vars are being set in embed tag.


    {stash:embed  
    context="@URI"  
    name="news_vm"  
    file_name="viewmodels:news_vm"  
    parse_stage="both"  
    stash:_channel="news"  
    ...  
    }